# Button errors after upgrading react-native-elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I have a big problem, because i need to upgrade libraries of some project, but I've never used React native. I upgrade `react-native-elements` form version 0.19 to 1.1 and I get many errors about unexisting properties in `Button` component.

Example part of code:

```
<Button
    backgroundColor={styles.palette.transparent}
    onPress={this.connectWithEmail}
    title={I18n.t('CONFIRM')}
    disabled={!this.state.password || !this.state.email}
    disabledStyle={styles.modal.actionButtonDisabled}
    underlayColor={styles.palette.transparent}
    containerViewStyle={styles.modal.actionButtonContainer}
    textStyle={[
        styles.modal.actionButtonText,
        {color: (this.state.password && this.state.email) ? styles.palette.secondary : styles.palette.textLight}
    ]}
/>
```

Ok, so I got error for this button like: 
`Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'` but I found info, that backgroundColor property is not exist in v 1.1 for button so I replace it using `buttonStyle` property in this way:

`buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: styles.palette.transparent}}`

My question is: 
**How can I replace the rest of missing props like: `underlayColor`, `containerViewStyle`, and `textStyle`?** I can't find any info about it in documentation and realese notes of react-native-documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`containerViewStyle` == `containerStyle`

`textStyle` == `titleStyle`

There is no `UnderlayColor` because the `react-native-elements` button is configured based on the `TouchableNativeFeedback` ' or `'TouchableOpacity'`.